# Delegate is not responding

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols

I am trying to call another method with Delegate and protocols in my app. I need to send the variable "myData" to another view but for some reasons it doesn't works. I don't know what I am doing wrong with the implementation of delegates and protocols. The delegate never call the action of the protocol.

Sorry I'm new with this.

BLEViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BLE.h"

@protocol EnviarDatos <NSObject>
//Metodo que se manda llamar pero se implementa en otra clase
-(void) actualizaDatos:(NSData*)Data;
@end

@interface BLEViewController : UITableViewController <BLEDelegate>
{
    //id <EnviarDatos> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic,assign)id delegate;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData *myData;
+ (BLE*) theBLEObject;

- (void) scanForPeripherals;
- (IBAction)connect:(id)sender;
-(void) activaProtocolo;

@end
```

BLEViewController.m

```
//
//  BLEViewController.m
//  DL_RemoteBLE_02
//
//  Created by Dave Lichtenstein on 3/16/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Dave Lichtenstein. All rights reserved.
//

#import "BLEViewController.h"

static BLE* ble;
static UILabel *statusLabel;
static NSString* connectionStatus = @"Not connected!";


@interface BLEViewController ()

@end

@implementation BLEViewController

@synthesize delegate;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if(ble==nil)
    {
        // Create our Bluetooth Low Energy object
        //
        ble = [[BLE alloc] init];
        [ble controlSetup];
        ble.delegate = self;
    }


        // Create a toolbar at the bottom of the screen to show status text, etc.
        //

        // get screen size
        //
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
        CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

        CGFloat toolbarHeight = 50.0;
        CGFloat labelHeight = 50.0;

    if(statusLabel==nil) // only create once
    {
        // create our status label object
        //
        statusLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, screenHeight-toolbarHeight-labelHeight, screenWidth, labelHeight)];

        statusLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        statusLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        statusLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];

        statusLabel.text = @"Connection Status:";
    }


    // create a toolbar
    //
    UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,screenHeight-toolbarHeight,screenWidth,toolbarHeight)];

    toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    /*UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 150, 20)];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
    label.text = @"Status:";
    UIBarButtonItem *labeltext = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:label];
    UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:nil];

    NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:statusLabel, nil];
    toolbar.items = items;
    */

    [self.view addSubview:statusLabel];
    [self.view addSubview:toolbar];


    // Update our status label
        statusLabel.text = connectionStatus;
    _myData = [[NSData alloc]init];
    delegate = self;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//-------------------------------------------------------
// methods
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
+ (BLE*) theBLEObject
{
    return ble;
}


-(void) connectionTimer:(NSTimer *)timer
{


    if (ble.peripherals.count > 0)
    {
        [ble connectPeripheral:[ble.peripherals objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
    NSLog(@"connectionTimer"); // diag
}

// We call this when the view loads to try to connect to our bluetooth perepheral
//
- (void) scanForPeripherals
{
    if (ble.activePeripheral)
        if(ble.activePeripheral.state == CBPeripheralStateConnected)
        {
            statusLabel.text = @"Disconnectng from peripheral...";
            [[ble CM] cancelPeripheralConnection:[ble activePeripheral]];
            return;
        }

    if (ble.peripherals)
        ble.peripherals = nil;


    NSLog(@"scanning...");
    statusLabel.text = @"Scanning for peripherals...";

    [ble findBLEPeripherals:2];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(float)2.0 target:self selector:@selector(connectionTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    //[indConnecting startAnimating];
}

- (IBAction)connect:(id)sender {

    [self scanForPeripherals];
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma mark - BLE delegate
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

NSTimer *rssiTimer;

// When Connected, this will be called
-(void) bleDidConnect
{
    NSLog(@"->Connected");
    statusLabel.text = @"Connected!";
    connectionStatus = @"Connected!";


    // Schedule to read RSSI every 1 sec.
    rssiTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(float)1.0 target:self selector:@selector(readRSSITimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}


// When RSSI is changed, this will be called
-(void) bleDidUpdateRSSI:(NSNumber *) rssi
{
    // Append the rssi value to our status label
    //
    NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@)", connectionStatus, rssi];

    statusLabel.text = temp;
}

-(void) readRSSITimer:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    [ble readRSSI];
}

// When data is comming, this will be called
-(void) bleDidReceiveData:(unsigned char *)data length:(int)length
{
    NSData *d = [NSData dataWithBytes:data length:length];
    _myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:data length:length];
    NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:d encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Datos en String %@",s);

    //_datosdelegate = self;

    //Is anyone listening
    if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(actualizaDatos:)])
    {
        //send the delegate function with the amount entered by the user
        [delegate actualizaDatos:_myData];
        NSLog(@"Entro delegado");
    }


}

- (void)bleDidDisconnect
{
    NSLog(@"->Disconnected");
    connectionStatus = @"Disconnected!";
    statusLabel.text = @"Disconnected!";

    [rssiTimer invalidate];
}

@end
```

sevenSegmentsViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BLEViewController.h"
#import "BLE.h"

@interface sevenSegmentsViewController : UIViewController<EnviarDatos>{
    UIImage *unoON;
    UIImage *dosON;
    UIImage *tresON;
    UIImage *cuatroON;
    UIImage *cincoON;
    UIImage *seisON;
    UIImage *sieteON;

    UIImage *unoOFF;
    UIImage *dosOFF;
    UIImage *tresOFF;
    UIImage *cuatroOFF;
    UIImage *cincoOFF;
    UIImage *seisOFF;
    UIImage *sieteOFF;

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *uno;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *dos;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *tres;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *cuatro;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *cinco;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *seis;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *siete;

@end
```

sevenSegmentsViewController.m

```
//
//  sevenSegmentsViewController.m
//  iShield
//
//  Created by Victor Carreño on 29/03/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 RedBearLab. All rights reserved.
//

#import "sevenSegmentsViewController.h"

@interface sevenSegmentsViewController ()

@end

@implementation sevenSegmentsViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    unoOFF = [UIImage imageNamed:@"7segnh.png"];
    dosOFF = [UIImage imageNamed:@"7segnv.png"];
    tresOFF = [UIImage imageNamed:@"7segnv.png"];
    cuatroOFF =[UIImage imageNamed:@"7segnh.png"];
    cincoOFF = [UIImage imageNamed:@"7segnh.png"];
    seisOFF = [UIImage imageNamed:@"7segnv.png"];
    sieteOFF = [UIImage imageNamed:@"7segnh.png"];

    unoON = [UIImage imageNamed:@"7segvh.png"];
    dosON = [UIImage imageNamed:@"7segvv.png"];
    tresON = [UIImage imageNamed:@"7segvv.png"];
    cuatroON =[UIImage imageNamed:@"7segvh.png"];
    cincoON = [UIImage imageNamed:@"7segvh.png"];
    seisON = [UIImage imageNamed:@"7segvv.png"];
    sieteON = [UIImage imageNamed:@"7segvh.png"];

    _uno = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:unoOFF];
    _dos = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:dosOFF];
    _tres = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:tresOFF];
    _cuatro = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:cuatroOFF];
    _cinco = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:cincoOFF];
    _seis = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:seisOFF];
    _siete = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:sieteOFF];

    //BLEViewController *myBLE = [[BLEViewController alloc]init];
    //BLE *myBLE = [BLEViewController theBLEObject];
    //NSLog(@"%@", myBLE.myData);

    BLEViewController *myBLE = [[BLEViewController alloc]init];
    myBLE.delegate = self;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
#pragma mark Delegado de Actualizar datos

-(void) actualizaDatos :(NSData *)myData{

    NSLog(@"Datos recividos");
    NSLog(@"Imprimio mi data con exitos %@", myData);

}

@end
```

Comment: You want `actualizaDatos:` to be called on your instance of `sevenSegmentsViewController` from an instance of `BLEViewController` right? However, I think there is problem with the instantiation of `myBLE` in `-[sevenSegmentsViewController viewDidLoad]`, in the sense that after the line `myBLE.delegate = self;`, the instance `myBLE` is soon to be deallocated, since it is not retained anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, your BLEViewController is setting its delegate property to "self" when I think you want it to get set to an instance of "sevenSegmentsViewController". As a result the "if([delegate respondsToSelector:..." test is failing and you are never hitting the call to actualizaDatos. If you are using protocols correctly, you don't really need to test for "respondsToSelector" because by definition, the delegate must support the protocol.

The compiler and IDE are not showing you the error because you declared the property of the BLEViewController as just type "id" instead of

```
id<EnviarDatos>
```

If you fix the property declaration to say that your delegate must support the right protocol, you'll immediately see the errors highlighted.

Comment: yup, I typed that, and somehow it got lost in formatting. Will edit now, thank you.